# URL scheme to access file from remote in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, networking, computer-science

I'm trying to access a file from remote host but within LAN. when I tried the below in my local, it is working.

`file://192.1.168.4/c:/Temp` at Chrome browser address bar

It is displaying the folder structure, however I applied the same concept with different IP (remote computer within LAN), it is not working.

After surfing, got to know that file:// URI scheme offers only accessing files with local computer.

Is there any alternate scheme to access files directories in remote computer from my computer, so that I can apply this concept to implement in Java programming?

Much appreciated help if anybody could.

Comment: There are multiple ways in which you can access files stored on a different system from your computer. You can set up a shared drive/folder on the remote system, setup a FTP server, etc. etc. What is it that you are exactly trying to achieve? Rather what do you mean by `so that I can apply this concept to implement in Java programming?`

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD basically i've to check some set of files and directories exists or not in some hundreds of remote systems. rather checking it manually, thought of writing a program to do that. Please suggest if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in that case (based on your answer to my question), it won't be that straightforward. It all depends - what's the OS on those remote systems, do you have administrator/root privileges on those systems, are those directories already exposed (i.e. shared). And that is only the first part, you'll then have to write something to access those shared folders, check whether they contain files/folders in your list, etc.

Having said that, a better alternative in my opinion would be to write a batch script/shell script that generates a list of (or a tree of) the root directory structure. Run it in every machine and save these generated directory trees somewhere else (along with machine information like hostname). Now, write a program that just checks for each hostname, whether a file/folder exists or not in the directory structure you previously exported.

For eg, you can run a batch file (assuming windows on the remote machines) that will print a directory tree structure, and store it in a shared folder on some other "Main" machine. Do it for every remote machine, so that in the shared folder on your "Main" machine, you have a list of files with directory structures, you can name those files such that they indicate what host they were generated on, e.g Machine1ListOfFiles.txt. Then run a java program that iterates over all these txt files, searches for particular files, and if not found, adds the filename to a new list. Thus, you'll get the names of all the machines that do not have those files/folders.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't want to run batch file in every machine that I want to check. I'll be having a list of hostnames and run from my machine to test each and every machine is having those specific files and directories. I have root access to all of those machines. What I'm really looking for is, there should be a URI scheme to access and represent files/directories, from that, I am planning to write a script or small utility program to do this task.

Comment: If those are windows machines, and if you have the necessary privileges on those machines, even a drive that isn't explicitly shared can be accessed by `\\HOSTNAME\\C$` through explorer. You can look into this, on how to access hidden shares through java or something.