Fetching remote files using file:// URI scheme in Python
There's a thread that talks about fetching local files with Python using a connection adapter. The solutions provided in that thread do not work for remote files (file://<host>/...path).
Is there a way to fetch these remote files via Python?

The file URI scheme doesn't specify a protocol to access remote files. You should use a more specific URI scheme, e.g. ftp://

@Barmar Thanks. I can use the URLs in Chromium-based browsers, any idea what happens under the hood? I'd use FTP, HTTP, ... if the host was under my control. Unfortunately the file URL is all I was given and no other protocol I've tried has worked out. What I'm trying to do is mirror some subdirectory, but nothing has been successful (Python, HTTrack, ...). Manually going through the subdirectory via the browser would be a pain. I guess I could automate navigation via the browser but if there's a more elegant solution I'd be happy to hear it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420749/url-scheme-to-access-file-from-remote-in-windows-7 shows someone accessing a file on a Windows machine on the LAN, so I suspect it uses SMB. Maybe it tries various network file sharing protocols to see what works. But there's no specificiation for this AFAIK.

@Barmar SMB works, thanks. I tested it via Python's smbprotocol lib. Feel free to add an answer and I'll award it.

I thought the point was that you wanted to use a generic URI rather than having to specify the protocol.

@Barmar Yeah, the question is generic as I don't know anything about the file URI scheme and didn't want to assume anything. My particular use-case merely involves crawling a remote directory (file://<remote host>/<subdir>/) which apparently accepts SMB. I guess if someone knows how browsers implemented it (or if there is some specification somewhere), that would probably be a proper answer.
